# How to open a new windows form by clicking on a listview item

Tags: vb.net, listview

As the title said i want to open a new specif window for each item that is clicked in a listview much like a contents page. The code i have so far is...

```
Private Sub LvLesson_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LvLesson.DoubleClick
    If LvLesson.FullRowSelect.ToString = "lesson 4" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Hello")
    End If
End Sub
```

the messagebox was just a test. I have four items lesson 1, 2, 3, 4 i simply want to click on 1 or 2 etc and open form 1 or 2 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/) is your friend.

[FullRowSelect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.fullrowselect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a **Boolean** property indicating whether the full row is selected or not when an item is clicked.

you want something like the [SelectedItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selecteditems%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property. This gives you access to the items of the listview that are currently selected.

For example:

```
Private Sub ListView1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.DoubleClick
    'Check we actually have something selected
    If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        'find out which items is selected and open the appropriate form
        Select Case ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Text
            Case "lesson 1"
                MessageBox.Show("Open Form 1")
            Case "lesson 2"
                MessageBox.Show("Open Form 2")
            Case "lesson 3"
                MessageBox.Show("Open Form 3")
            Case "lesson 4"
                MessageBox.Show("Open Form 4")
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```